# Context lost in parent component when called from child

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I've got a parent component which feeds a `onSomeAction` prop to a child component:

```
export default class myComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
           <div className="mycomponent">
             <ChildComponent onSomeAction={this.doSomething} />
           </div>
        )
    }

    doSomething() {
        console.log(this);
    }
}
```

In the child component when something is clicked on I'm calling a method whiih in turns calls the `onSomeAction` prop:

```
export default class ChildComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
           <div className="">
             <a onClick={() => this.doIt()}>doIt</a>
           </div>
        )
    }

    doIt() {
        const { onSomeAction } = this.props;
        onSomeAction();
    }
}
```

The problem I'm seeing is back in the parent component the this context seems to have been lost - the `console.log` in the `doSomething` method returns undefined. Why is this? I need to be able to access
the parent component context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need set context in parent component, you can do it with [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
<ChildComponent onSomeAction={ this.doSomething.bind(this) } />
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/29343/)

Answer (score 0):

There are two options for you on how you can get the element that has been clicked or the whole component scope this.

option one:
instead of logging this you should logg the event target like so:

```
    doSomething(e) {
        console.log(e.target);
    }
```

option two:
you have to attach the this keyword to the doSomething method like so:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.doSomething = this.doSomething.bind(this);
}
```

That was you'll be able to access the keyword `this` in your do something method.

Option3:

If you want to refer with this to the child component then you have to bind(this) on the function call int he child component

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can fix it 3 ways:

1. `<ChildComponent onSomeAction={ this.doSomething.bind(this) } />`
2. `<ChildComponent onSomeAction={ () => this.doSomething() } />`
3. `<ChildComponent onSomeAction={this.doSomething} />`
    and add this to constructor: `this.doSomething = this.doSomething.bind(this)`